# How do I use TKinter to select two excel files as keep them as files?

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter

I am using some stock TKInter code to select two separate Excel/csv files:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

root = tk.Tk()
file_1 = fd.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Choose a file')
file_2 = fd.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Choose a file')
```

What I want to do is to select two csv/Excel files and then compare them using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

def cleanup():

    file_1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name="***")
    file_2 = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name="***")

    df = pd.merge(
    left=file_1,
    right=file_2,
    left_on="User Name",
    right_on = "ExternalID",
    how = "right")
    matched = df.to_csv("matched.csv", index=False)
    return matched
```

The error I get is the following: "TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'tuple'> was passed." How can I use TkInter to select the file and treat it as a Dataframe converted from excel/csv?

Answer (score 1):

`fd.askopenfilenames` returns a *tuple* of file names, since users can select multiple files in one dialog.

```py
# Note the trailing comma to extract the a single path.
file_1, = fd.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Choose a file')
file_2, = fd.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Choose a file')

# Or use fd.askopenfilename (note the singular "name").
file_1 = fd.askopenfilename(parent=root, title='Choose a file')
file_2 = fd.askopenfilename(parent=root, title='Choose a file')

excel_1 = pd.read_excel(file_1, sheet_name="***")
excel_2 = pd.read_excel(file_2, sheet_name="***")

df = pd.merge(left=excel_1, right=excel_2, ...)
```

Also note that your `cleanup` method is parsing the same file twice:

```py
file_1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name="***")
file_2 = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name="***")
#                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use `fd.askopenfilename()` when a single filepath is desired?

Comment: @drchicken good point, I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm getting "None," as the only output. I'm assuming that's indicting there's no matches between the two files?

Comment: @user22241444 The none is probably because you're saving the output to a file (`df.to_csv("matched.csv", index=False)`) instead of generating a string. Check the file for the results.

Answer (score 1):

BoppreH gets to the heart of the issue; the file dialog returns a tuple of file names, not the files themselves.

If your files are in the same folder, another option is to use this code and select both files from the same dialog. Whichever you click first will become `file_1`.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk()
file_names = fd.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Choose two files')

def cleanup():

    file_1 = pd.read_excel(file_names[0], sheet_name="***")
    file_2 = pd.read_excel(file_names[1], sheet_name="***")

    df = pd.merge(
        left=file_1,
        right=file_2,
        left_on="User Name",
        right_on = "ExternalID",
        how = "right")
    matched = df.to_csv("matched.csv", index=False)
    return matched

print(cleanup())
```